# Timed out error when running a selfhosted domain

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, timeout, self-hosting, jitsi

I was trying to selfhost jitsi meet (used for video conferencing) through my raspberry pi 4
I have followed this [tutorial](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-quickstart?fbclid=IwAR0u_zDsJPf35xGMftHsrUlLG13WqB_GcBjJBiqmQXVE-yHJyKcKS26B8hA#openjdk-8)
Now, when I try to open my domain (I've got it from no-ip) it takes too long then shows this error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
In a video I watched they say wait a few minutes for the domain to propagate
I have waited for 30 minutes and its not up yet, have I waited long enough? if yes, does that mean something else is wrong? what could it be?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

okay its over
just don't believe anyone who tells you to close port 80 after downloading the keys
open ports: 80, 443,4443, 10000